# Composer: loading custom classes

Tags: php, composer-php

I've just started to work with Composer, but I can't really grasp how I should solve the following issue:
**how do I set up so I don't have to state \Other\ when using a class?** (i.e. so my custom classes works like the Mustache classes)

**This works**

```
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine();
$foo = new \Other\SimpleClass();
```

**This does not work**

```
$foo = new SimpleClass();
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Other": "lib/",
        "Mustache": "lib/"
    }
}
}
```

**Folder structure**

```
/lib
  /Mustache
  /Other
```

I have entered `namespace Other;` in all files in my Other-folder

Comment: I have tried changing "Other": "lib/" to "Other": "lib/Other",

Comment: That has nothing to do with composer, but with whether the classes are namespaced.

Comment: Hey @PeeHaa. Thanks for the reply! Isn't adding "namespace Other;" to the files with the classes enough?

Comment: Yes either you are in the same namespace or you alias it using the `use` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being slow, but I still don't understand why $mustache = new Mustache_Engine(); doesn't have to be $mustache = new \Mustache\Mustache_Engine();

Comment: Because it's not in a namespace http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I set up so I don't have to state \Other\ when using a class?

Don't strive for not using namespaces.

Not using namespaces makes only sense for really small scripts, which run standalone and don't reuse pieces of code from other vendors (components/libraries).

> I still don't understand why `$mustache = new Mustache_Engine();` doesn't have to be `$mustache = new \Mustache\Mustache_Engine();`

`Mustache_Engine` is not namespaced (yet).

They use a string-prefix-namespace: they simply add `Mustache_` to the classname `Engine` to avoid class name collision with other classes called `Engine`. This code will run on old and newer PHP versions.

Eventually, it will be come `\Mustache\Engine`, when the Mustache developers update the code to make use of namespaces. This code will only run on PHP versions, which support namespaces as a language feature.

**Autoloading of Mustache**

If you installed Mustache using Composer

```
{
    "require": {
        "mustache/mustache": "^2.9"
    }
}
```

then Composer will generate the autoloading for Mustache automatically.

You don't have to add a PSR-0 directive to `composer.json` to get it working.

You only need to set PSR-0, if you downloaded and extracted Mustache manually into the `/lib` folder. This is the old way of working with dependencies - leverage Composer instead.

Comment: @jens-a-koch Thanks! Really appreciate it! I'll change to use the require-way instead of psr-0 for Mustache.

Regarding my own classes, I used "classmap": ["libraries/Other"]. Should I namespace them and approach it in a different way?

Comment: Well, using `classmap` works, but i would suggest to use namespaces and then add a `psr-4` entry in the `autoload` section. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4